# How to write into a generic array using a method? Generic array doesn't change datatype after specifying the type

Tags: c#, arrays, generics

How could I use the method writeArray to write values into the generic array T[]? Compiler gives an error, see the comment in the code.

It seems the generic array is still generic as T.
I thought by initializing the intObj with specifying that T is int, every placeholder T in the object is now datatype int? So with this.array[i] where the error happens, I expected T[] to turn to int[]. Thank you in advance.

```
class GenericArray<T> {
    Random rnd=new Random();
    T[] array = new T[3];
    
    public void writeArray() {
        for (int i = 0; i<this.array.Length; i++) {
            this.array[i]=rnd.Next(1,10);   //Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'T'
        }
    }
}

class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        GenericArray<int> intObj = new GenericArray<int>();
        
        intObj.writeArray();
        }
}
```

Comment: What if I did `new GenericArray<string>().writeArray();`? It sounds like you don't need generics at all.

Comment: It's just practice for me on how generics work. Using GenericArray<string> generate the same error (can't convert the random int numbers to T)

Comment: I'm asking you to think about what would happen if I did `new GenericArray<string>().writeArray();`. It's supposed to be a pedagogical device, not supposed to fix your code. Keep in mind that `T`, as a generic type parameter, can be anything, so does it make sense to call `writeArray` on a `GenericArray<string>` object? Now do you understand why your code doesn't compile?

Comment: I'm sorry, I must be missing some important knowledge because I can't really think of anything. Maybe with `GenericArray<string>` the method `writeArray` could also not convert the random numbers from int to string? And the compiler just doesn't say "can't convert from int to string" but instead "int to T"?

Comment: Exactly. `T` isn't necessarily an `int`, right? If it happened to be `string`, then the integer returned by `rnd.Next` isn't the correct type anymore! The compiler has to be able to prove that your code is type-safe in _all_ situations. This is why it tries to convert an `int` to `T`. The only type that you can put into the array is `T` - all other types would fail in _some_ situations. If you put in an `int`, then it wouldn't work if `T` turned out to be `string`, for example.

Comment: "The compiler has to be able to prove that your code is type-safe in all situations." I think this is the important part that I didn't know. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Something that may help you is to mention that generic is not the same thing as dynamic. `T` won't magically change to different types just because it is generic. Anywhere you use a generic class, you have to specify the type and when generics are used the type will be defined at compile time and won't change during runtime.

Answer (score 1):

A class that is generic over `T` must be able to handle all types of `T`. That means that `writeArray` has to work no matter what `T` was specified. Your version won't work, of course, if `T` is anything other than a numeric data type, because `Random` always generates numbers. Hence it's not allowed.

What we need to do is rewrite your class so that it only contains the code that is generic to all `T`.

```
abstract class GenericArray<T>
{
    protected T[] array = new T[3];

    protected abstract T GenerateRandomValue();

    public void WriteArray()
    {
        for (int i=0; i<this.array.Length; i++)
        {
            this.array[i] = GenerateRandomValue();
        }
    }
}
```

This makes sense because we know how to store an array of any `T` (we declare it), and we know how to loop over an array of any `T` (we use `for`), but we don't know how to generate a random value for any `T` (so we leave that out as `abstract`).

When you need to include type-specific logic, you can close the type (inherit from it and state the type parameter) and provide the implementation there.

```
class IntegerArray : GenericArray<int>
{
    Random rnd = new Random();

    protected override int GenerateRandomValue() => rnd.Next(1,10);
}
```

And of course you can do this for other types. Here it is for a string. Since `Random` produces numbers, we need to use a different function to get a random *string*. In this example I just use a GUID.

```
class StringArray : GenericArray<string>
{
    protected override string GenerateRandomValue() => System.Guid.NewGuid.ToString();
}
```

And just to drive the point home, here's one more example using a complex type for `T`.

```
class PointArray : GenericArray<Point>
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    protected override Point GenerateRandomValue() => new Point(rnd.Next(0,100), rnd.Next(0,100));
}
```

Now you can do this in your main program:

```
var array = new IntegerArray();
array.WriteArray();
```

Comment: I must be doing something wrong. `protected override T GenerateRandomValue() => rnd.Next(1,10);` gives me errors `type or namespace name 'T' could not be found` and `'IntegerArray.GenerateRandomValue()': return type must be 'int' to match overridden member 'GenericArray<int>.GenerateRandomValue()'.` Since IntergerArray inherited from GenericArray<int>, T should have been converted to int, no? And therefore the returntype `T`doesn't exist anymore and can't be used by `GenerateRandomValue()`

Comment: Sorry, I’m AFK and didn’t try to compile, so there’s bound to be some errors. I just made some changes, try again please.

Comment: Yeah now it works. Thank you very much, I'll make sure to study this.

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
this.array[i]=rnd.Next(1,10);
```

`rand.Next()` returns an int; it always returns an int, regardless of what you write in your own class that calls `Next()`. The left-hand operand always has type `T`. How would compiler know what to do if you passed, for example, a `string` (as said in comments) or, let's say, a `FileStream`? How would it guess what kind of result do you expect when assigning an `int` to be a `FileStream`?

What you *can* do is provide a way for your generic class to get an object of type T from int, either on creation or right in `WriteArray()` method:

```
class GenericArray<T> 
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    T[] array = new T[3];
    
    public void WriteArray(Func<int, T> FuncToGetTFromInt) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<this.array.Length; i++) 
        {
            this.array[i] = FuncToGetTFromInt(rnd.Next(1,10));   
        }
    }
}
```

And you'd use it like that:

```
Func<int, string> FuncToGetStringFromInt = (value) => 
{
    return $"This int's value was {value.ToString()}";
}; 
intObj.writeArray(FuncToGetStringFromInt);
```

Or (preferably) you'd provide the whole function that gives random objects of type T:

```
public void writeRandomArray(Func<T> FuncToGetRandomT) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i<this.array.Length; i++) 
    {
        this.array[i] = FuncToGetRandomT();   
    }
}
```

And use it like that:

```
Random rnd = new Random();

GenericArray<string> aStr = new GenericArray<string>();
Func<string> FuncToGetRandomString = () => {return $"Hello world {rnd.Next()}!";};  
aStr.WriteRandomArray(FuncToGetRandomString);

GenericArray<int> aInt = new GenericArray<int>();
Func<int> FuncToGetRandomInt = () => {return rnd.Next();};
aInt.WriteRandomArray(FuncToGetRandomInt);
```